# Looping over 2 jsons and performing a task based on some condition

Tags: ansible

I have a json file machine.json, whose content is like this,

```json
{
"oda8m007": {
    "nodename": ["oda8m007"],
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "type":lite

 },
"oda8m032": {
    "nodename": ["oda8m032"],
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "type":lite
 },
"oda708c1n1": {
    "nodename": ["oda708c1n1","oda708c1n2"],
    "domain": “abc.com",
    "type":medium
    
  }
}
```

I have another json nodes.json, whose content is like this,

```json
{
  "hosts": ["oda708c1n1","oda8m032"]
}
```

my inventory file looks like this,

```ini
[odalites]
oda8m032 ansible_ssh_pass=welcome1 
oda708c1n1 ansible_ssh_pass=welcome1
```

and finally, my playbook is as follows,

```yaml
---
  - name: Print inventory hosts
    hosts: odalites
    gather_facts: no
    vars:
      nodes : "{{ lookup('file','nodes') | from_json }}"
      machines : "{{ lookup('file','machine.json') | from_json}}"
    tasks:
    - name: Cleanup the nodes
      debug:
        msg: "{{machines.inventory_hostname}}"        
      with_items: "{{nodes.hosts}}"
      when: item == inventory_hostname
```

On running the playbook I see this error,

```
[root@odaautomation pyscripts]# ansible-playbook cleanuphosts.yaml -i odalite_inventory

PLAY [Print inventory hosts] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Cleanup the nodes] ***************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [oda8m032] => (item=oda708c1n1) 
fatal: [oda8m032]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'inventory_hostname'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/odaautomation/pyscripts/cleanuphosts.yaml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    tasks:\n    - name: Cleanup the nodes\n      ^ here\n"}
fatal: [oda708c1n1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'inventory_hostname'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/odaautomation/pyscripts/cleanuphosts.yaml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    tasks:\n    - name: Cleanup the nodes\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************
oda708c1n1              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
oda8m032                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

My requirement is that I should the list of nodename from each entry in the machine.json and run a script on those nodes. For example, as per the above inventory file, I want to run cleanup.sh on oda708c1n1 , oda708c1n2 and oda8m032

Comment: How would you like to run *cleanup.sh* on *oda708c1n2*? There is no such host in the inventory.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, that's the ask here, "My requirement is that I should the list of nodename from each entry in the machine.json and run a script on those nodes"
Here, machine.json has the following entry for nodename for scaoda708c1n1..

"oda708c1n1": {
    "nodename": ["oda708c1n1","oda708c1n2"],
    "domain": “abc.com",
    "type":medium
}

So, I would need to run cleanup on both the nodes oda708c1n1 and oda708c1n2

Comment: Iterate *nodename*. I added an example.

Comment: What is the purpose of *nodes.json*?

Comment: Realized that nodes.json is actually not needed as we traversing the inventory file anyway. Thanks for the example @vladimir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop below does nothing

```yaml
      debug:
        msg: "{{machines.inventory_hostname}}"        
      with_items: "{{nodes.hosts}}"
      when: item == inventory_hostname
```

It runs the task only once for *inventory_hostname*. The variable *item* isn't used. The reference to *machines* is wrong. This can be reduced and fixed to

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ machines[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Given the valid JSON dictionaries

```yaml
shell> cat nodes.json 
{
  "hosts": ["oda708c1n1","oda8m032"]
  }
```

```yaml
shell> cat machine.json
{
"oda8m007": {
    "nodename": ["oda8m007"],
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "type": "lite"

 },
"oda8m032": {
    "nodename": ["oda8m032"],
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "type": "lite"
 },
"oda708c1n1": {
    "nodename": ["oda708c1n1", "oda708c1n2"],
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "type": "medium"
    
  }
}
```

The play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: odalites

  vars:

    nodes: "{{ lookup('file','nodes.json') }}"
    machines: "{{ lookup('file', 'machine.json') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: nodes|to_yaml
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: machines|to_yaml
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ machines[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [odalites] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [oda8m032] => 
  nodes|to_yaml: |-
    hosts: [oda708c1n1, oda8m032]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [oda8m032] => 
  machines|to_yaml: |-
    oda708c1n1:
      domain: abc.com
      nodename: [oda708c1n1, oda708c1n2]
      type: medium
    oda8m007:
      domain: abc.com
      nodename: [oda8m007]
      type: lite
    oda8m032:
      domain: abc.com
      nodename: [oda8m032]
      type: lite

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [oda8m032] => 
  msg:
    domain: abc.com
    nodename:
    - oda8m032
    type: lite
ok: [oda708c1n1] => 
  msg:
    domain: abc.com
    nodename:
    - oda708c1n1
    - oda708c1n2
    type: medium

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
oda708c1n1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
oda8m032: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***List nodename from each entry and run a script on it.***

A: Iterate the list *nodename*. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Cleanup {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ machine.nodename }}"
      vars:
        machine: "{{ machines[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [oda8m032] => (item=oda8m032) => 
  msg: Cleanup oda8m032
ok: [oda708c1n1] => (item=oda708c1n1) => 
  msg: Cleanup oda708c1n1
ok: [oda708c1n1] => (item=oda708c1n2) => 
  msg: Cleanup oda708c1n2
```

Answer (score 0):

Much like python Ansible has the builtin `zip` command which should solve your problem

```yaml
- name: Iterate over pairs of objects
  debug:
    msg: "Item 1: {{ item.0 }}, Item 2: {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ list1 | zip(list2) | list }}"
```